# How to set idle timeout in quarkus when we limit the maximum number of http connections

Tags: quarkus, vert.x

https://quarkus.io/guides/http-reference#http-limits-configuration

```
quarkus.http.limits.max-connections

The maximum number of connections that are allowed at any one time. If this is set it is recommended to set a short idle timeout.
```

what does this exactly mean and what is the property to set the idle timeout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that Quarkus will limit the number of open HTTP connections to whatever you have set.

The reason we recommend to also set a low idle timeout via `quarkus.http.idle-timeout` (depends on the application, but you probably want something in the low seconds), is that if you have idle connections sitting around and have the number of maximum available connections, you could run out of connections very quickly.

P.S. All Quarkus configuration options can be found [here](https://quarkus.io/guides/all-config).

Comment: is there a property to set idle timeout

Comment: See my updated answer